# Can RL solve scheduling problems with unknown function

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, multi-armed-bandits

I have the following scheduling problem.

- There are $n$ tasks and $m>n$ machines.
- Each task $i$ has a requirement $t_i$ that should be guaranteed.
- Any task can be scheduled on at least one machine but a machine cannot schedule more that one task.
- When a task $i$ is scheduled on machines $S_i\subset\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$, the machines in $S_i$ should be consecutive meaning that the set $S_i$ is of the form $S_i=\{j,j+1,\ldots,j+|S_i|-1\}$, for some $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$.
- Given the scheduling $S_1,\ldots,S_n$, we can compute a satisfaction value for each task $i$ scheduled on machine $j\in S_i$ as $f_{ij}(S_1,\ldots,S_n)>0$, which is unknown. I only have access to a black-box to compute $f_{ij}(\cdot)$. So, given $S_1,\ldots,S_n$, I can find the satisfaction value for each task $i$ and each machine $j\in S_i$.
- We have to guarantee that each task $i$ has the sum of its satisfaction values of its machines is at least $t_i$, i.e., $\sum_{j\in S_i}f_{ij}(S_1,\ldots,S_n)\geq t_i$.
- The objective is to maximize the sum of all satisfaction values, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\in S_i}f_{ij}(S_1,\ldots,S_n)$.

Is RL a good approach to solve this problem. What RL algorithm do you suggest and why?
I was trying to model it using MAB but when I was defining the arms I figured out that the number of arms can be the possible partitions of $m$ into $n$ tasks (with permutations). So for $m=70$ and $n=6$, I have 11238513 arms. So, I don't know if it is possible to apply MAB. Even with RL, that action space will be very large and should the RL assume terminal reward game or step reward game?

Comment: from your formulation, you have more machines than tasks

Comment: Yes exactly. A task is heavy and needs more than one machine to be executed.